# Need a good unmanaged C++ OCX example

Tags: c++, ocx

I need a very simple and clear example of how to create an OCX in unmanaged C++ code. Ideally, I'd like to consume it in Office, but any container (i.e. VB6, .NET WinForms) should be good.

I am having trouble seeing how I can add controls to the OCX canvas... I have seen examples of opening dialogs from within the OCX's load event... but that is not what I want... I need the GUI in the OCX itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [this Microsoft tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa136657.aspx). It uses MFC. If you want to create a windowless control you would need to use ATL.